# PHP after Register success show JS Alert

Tags: javascript, php, alert, message

I have a login with a register process function like this:

```
if($result) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> window.location.href = "index.php"; </script>';
    include ("alert.php");
    $showFormular = false;
} else {
    echo 'Beim Abspeichern ist leider ein Fehler aufgetreten<br>';          
}
```

But i want that if the $result in top, a javascript with an alert is running,but it dosnt work.The alert code is:

```
<script src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/sweetalert2/6.6.2  /sweetalert2.min.js"> </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/sweetalert2/6.6.2/sweetalert2.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/core-js/2.4.1/core.js"> </script>

<script>
window.onload = function ()
{
    swal({
        title:"Erfolgreich",
        type:"success",
        background:"#f2f2f2",
        confirmButtonColor:"#0080ff"
    })
}
</script>
```

Comment: what is `$result` how does it populates and you are using `window.location.href` the code after it wont be called as it would redirect, how do you expect to use `include ("alert.php");` after that

Comment: The $result is not important for you but if it true than shoud you get an alert and redirect to the page this is the reason why im using window.locate

Answer (score 0):

You're redirecting the page before executing `include ("alert.php");`.

Either move `include ("alert.php");` to `index.php` or move `include ("alert.php");` above `echo '<script type="text/javascript"> window.location.href = "index.php"; </script>';`